# How to remove Search Box from page if no result?

Tags: php, search-box

I have two search boxes, one on top, and one on bottom.
The content is in the middle, if found no results, how do I remove one of them? (bottom one)

Thanks

I got this for the form:

```
<form class="form" name="search" method="_post" action="index.php"><br>
<input style="width:300px; height:28px; vertical-align:middle;" class="searchbox" type="text" name="q" value="<? print $info['keyword']; ?>"/>
<select name="type" style="height:28px; width:100px; font-size:18px; vertical-align:middle; margin-left:3px; margin-right:2px;">    <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" style="width:80px; height:28px; font-size:16px; text-align:justify; vertical-align:middle;" /><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="stype" value="all" <? if(!isset($_GET['stype'])||$_GET['stype']=="all") print "checked";?> /> all files
<input type="radio" name="stype" value="checked" <? if(!isset($_GET['stype'])||$_GET['stype']=="checked") print "checked";?> /> checked files
```

Comment: You could do this several ways.  One would be to check your content element (via javaScript) to see if anything returned.  If it didn't then you can change the display style to none.  The other way would be to do a check in php for the results and if no results returned then just don't echo out your search box.  Without more code though it is really difficult to see what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if(count($results):?>
<form class="form" name="search" method="_post" action="index.php"><br>...
<?php endif;?>
```

That's a best guess with the information you gave (no code, etc.)